# Error 424 object required when using two If statements

Tags: vba

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If (TextBox1.Value = "goals") Then
         s = MsgBox("write down your goals", vbYesNo, "goals")
    End If

    If (s = MsgBoxResult.Yes) Then
        InputBox("", "goals", "", 50, 50)
    End If
End Sub
```

It is supposed to create an input box if you press yes on the message box but it gives me error 424 object required and the debugger highlights the if statement that checks if you clicked yes.

Comment: You want to use an input box, not a message box s = InputBox("Write down your Goals")

Comment: And your later inputbox should be a messagebox

Comment: but i am checking if you want to so if you press no it doesn't open the input box

Comment: `MsgBoxResult.Yes` should be `vbMsgBoxResult.vbYes`

Comment: i am new-------

Comment: ok i will try that

Comment: ok thanks YowE3k it worked

Answer (score 2):

`MsgBoxResult.*` is the [.NET Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.msgboxresult%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and doesn't work in VBA.

You need to use VbMsgBoxResult.

Change the second if clause to:

```
If (s = VbMsgBoxResult.vbYes) Then
    m = InputBox("", "goals", "", 50, 50)
End If
```

---

Like stated by @YowE3K, this will work too:

```
If (s = vbYes) Then
    m = InputBox("", "goals", "", 50, 50)
End If
```

Comment: Note: The `vbMsgBoxResult.` isn't normally required.  (I had to look up the library to check what it actually was!)  It really would only be needed if the developer accidentally(?) created their own `vbYes` variable and therefore needed to fully qualify the built-in one to avoid conflicts with their own one.  But it doesn't hurt fully qualifying it.